# ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table

Tags: mysql, sql

I read the already posted answers to my question but finally they did not help.
So I know that in MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.
But: How would the following SQL statement work?

```
update keys_from_table_sorted
set    l.nummer =
   (select @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
   from   keys_from_table_sorted l
   join   (select @curRow := 0) r);
```

I try to update the field 'nummer' in the table 'keys_from_table_sorted' with the row_number from the select statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way

```
SET @curRow := 0;
UPDATE keys_from_table_sorted
   SET nummer = (@curRow := @curRow + 1)
 ORDER BY <column_name> -- You should specify order
```

**Note:** that order of records are not guaranteed unless you use `ORDER BY` clause. Therefore always specify it explicitly whether it's a `SELECT` or an `UPDATE`. Otherwise you may get meaningless row numbers.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c482/1)** demo

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?